# Apache Tomcat standalone or with nginx or apache?

Tags: linux, debian, tomcat, jsp, servlets

I will be rolling out a fairly big project that will be running on Tomcat. I will have a linux VPS for it (Debian). i wanted to know if it is recommended to run it by itself or behind a httpserver such as apache or nginx.

Answer (score 2):

It is a question that requires a detailed answer and there are many resources on the web that will be elaborate. I would be succinct. 
If there are static resources such as js, css then nginx / apache can take care of it. If SSL termination / compression is required then nginx / apache can offload that. Also, nginx / apache provide for more bells and whistles in terms of configuration such as rewriting, use nginx / apache. One could also use Nginx as a load balancer to more than one backend tomcats as well. 
Also, note that introducing a web server in the mix would lead to another hop from the client to tomcat.